# Falha ao buildar aplicação Spring MVC ao configurar bean AOP

Tags: java, spring, exceção, spring-mvc, aop

Estou tentando configurar o AOP no spring.xml da minha aplicação Spring MVC, porém não consigo buildar.

Consultei a documentação, porém seguindo-a não obtive sucesso.

O código está da seguinte forma:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd">

<aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>

<!-- Aspect -->
<bean id="logAspect" class="br.com.imts.interceptor.ErrorInterceptor" />
```

Minha classe Java:

```
@Aspect
public class ErrorInterceptor{

SendMailService sendMailService;

@AfterThrowing(pointcut = "execution(* br.com..* (..))", throwing = "ex")
public void errorInterceptor(Exception ex) {
   if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
    logger.debug("Interceptor inicializado");
   }
   String mensagem = "Ocorreu um erro no sistema xyz. " + ex.getMessage();

   sendMailService.send(mensagem);

   if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
    logger.debug("Interceptor finalizado.");
   }
  }
 }
```

E o início da Exception lançada:

```
Jun 24, 2016 10:34:01 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name              
'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor':       Cannot resolve reference to bean
'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0' while setting bean property 'transactionAttributeSource'; nested 
exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 
'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0': BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception 
is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aspectj/weaver/reflect/ReflectionWorld$ReflectionWorldException
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1477)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1222)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.BeanFactoryAdvisorRetrievalHelper.findAdvisorBeans(BeanFactoryAdvisorRetrievalHelper.java:92)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findCandidateAdvisors(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:101)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator.findCandidateAdvisors(AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator.java:85)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.autoproxy.AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.shouldSkip(AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:103)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:243)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:984)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.resolveBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:955)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getSingletonFactoryBeanForTypeCheck(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:858)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:790)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isTypeMatch(AbstractBeanFactory.java:542)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:739)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4729)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5167)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Existe algo errado no meu xml pra não estar buildando?

Comment: Tá usando maven? Se sim, adiciona essa dependência, você deve escolher a que tem a mesma versão do Spring que você usa https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-aspects

Comment: Estou usando Maven, resolveu meu problema. Obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema está nessa linha:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aspectj/weaver/reflect/ReflectionWorld$ReflectionWorldException
```

Está faltando uma depedência no seu projeto referente ao aspectj.

Para efetuar a correção você pode adicionar essa dependência no seu projeto:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Na opção `<version>` você deve colocar a mesma versão do Spring que você está usando